# Confirm that the identity $1+z+...+z^n=(1-z^{n+1})/(1-z)$ holds for every non-negaive integer $n$ and every complex number $z$, save for $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, induction

**Confirm that the identity $1+z+...+z^n=(1-z^{n+1})/(1-z)$ holds for every non-negaive integer $n$ and every complex number $z$, save for $z=1$**

I have tried to prove this by induction but I am not sure that I am doing things right, for $ n = 1 $ we have $ (1-z ^ 2) / (1-z) = (1-z) (1+ z) / (1-z) = 1 + z $, then this holds for $ n = 1 $. Suppose now that it holds for $ n $ and see that it holds for $ n + 1 $,$1+z+...+z^n+z^{n+1}=(1-z^{n+1})/(1-z)+z^{n+1}=[(1-z^{n+1})+(1-z)(z^{n+1})]/(1-z)=(1-z^{n+2})/(1-z) $  then this is true for every non-negative integer $ n$. This is OK?

Comment: Since you want to avoid $z=1$ anyway, you are allowed to multiply both sides by the (then non-zero) factor $1-z$

Comment: Do you know geometric sequences.

Comment: It's OK to me at least. Do you want to see my proof?

Comment: @BAI Yes, please

Comment: Yes.  That is jut fine.  Or as Hagen von Eitzen suggests proving $1 + ... +z^n = (1-z^{n+1})/(1-z)$ is the same thing as proving $(1-z)(1+.... +z^n) = (1 - z^{n+1})$ which is provable via inductin by noting $(1-z)(1+ .... + z^n + z^{n+1}) = (1-z)(1+....+ z^n) + (1-z)z^{n+1} = 1-z^{n+1} + z^{n+1} - z^{n+2} = 1 - z^{n+2}$.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima No, I do not know, why?

Comment: This identity is valid in *any* field since the identity $1-a^{n+1}=(1-a)(1+a+\dots+a^n)$ is valid in any commutative ring.

Comment: @Bernard It's true in *any* ring (commutativity is not needed).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: True. Actually I was mainly thinking of fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My proof goes like this:
Let $S:=1+z+z^2+...+z^n$
Then
$$zS=z+z^2+z^3+...+z^{n+1}$$
$$zS=S-1+z^{n+1}$$
$$(1-z)S=1-z^{n+1}$$
As $z\neq 1$, it gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

By induction,

Assume that
$$1+z+z^2+...+z^n=\frac {1-z^{n+1}}{1-z} $$

then
$$1+z+...+z^n+z^{n+1}=$$
$$\frac {1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}+z^{n+1}= $$
$$\frac {1-z^{n+1}+z^{n+1}-z^{n+2}}{1-z} $$

Done.

Answer (score 1):

You can also prove that

$(1-z)\sum_{i=0}^n z^i=$

$\sum_{i=0}^n (1-z)z^i=$ (technically this assummes distribution is known for all finite sums;  that can be proven by induction for the precise and anal).

$\sum_{i=0}^n (z^i-z^{i+1})=$

$\sum_{i=0}^nz^i - \sum_{i=0}^nz^{i+1}= $ (technically we must prove associativity of addition will hold for all finite sums... which is a proof by induction)

$\sum_{i=0}^nz^i - \sum_{j=1}^{n+1}z^{j}= $ (relabel $j = i+1$)

$\sum_{k=0}^nz^i - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}z^{k}= $ (relabel $k = i$ on the left and $k = j$ on the right)

$(1 + \sum_{k=1}^n z^k) - (\sum_{k=1}^nz^k - z^{n+1}) = $

$1 + (\sum_{i=1}^n z^i - \sum_{i=1}^n z^i) - z^{n+1} =$ (ditto the assumption about associativity.)

$1 - z^{n+1}$.